# Adding constraint to css file for a QWidget

Tags: c++, css, qt

I use a css file in my Qt Projets, with Visual Studio 2010.

main.cpp :

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// Mise en place du style CSS
QFile File("Resources/style.css");
File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString styleSheet = File.readAll();
File.close();
app.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

A part of my css file :

```
QWidget#contenuDescription {
    background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

QLabel#nom1 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);
    font-size: 36px;
}

QLabel#nom2 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);
    font-size: 24px;
}

QLabel#nom3 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 150, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I want to change the color to my QLabels : nom1, nom2 and nom3 when `bool m_changeColor == true`.

I know we can use `::hover` if we want to change the style sheet when the mouse is on the QLabel. Something like this does it exist for my problem ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Would it not be possible to simply add more classes to the css and change the classes of your labels when you want to change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use properties:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool changeColor ...)
```

Os set a property [dynamically](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties):

```
nom1Label->setProperty("changeColor", true);
```

Then in CSS:

```
QLabel#nom1[changeColor="true"] {
    ...
}
```

Also note:

> Warning: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet
>   has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet
>   recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and
>   set it again.

Comment: This is exactly I wanted. Now I don't know how unset the style sheet because my style sheet is set for QApplication, but I am going to find a solution. Thx a lot svlasov.

Comment: You can just set an empty style sheet like `app.setStyleSheet("");`

Comment: QApplication is in my main.cpp and I use the style sheet in my different classes ...

Comment: So I do that :  
  `qApp->setStyleSheet("");
  m_contenu->setProperty("couleurFond", 0);
  QFile File("Resources/style.css");
  File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
  QString styleSheet = File.readAll();
  File.close();
  qApp->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);`

You don't think is not a too "hard" way ?

Comment: You need to reset (unset and set again) the stylesheet only when changing the property, but it **might not** be necessary. Also, no need to set empty stylesheet in the very fist time, when the app starts it has no stylesheet (unless you use `-stylesheet` command line option).